# Formatting potentially infected USB stick before plugging it into trusted devices

Tags: usb-drive, virus-removal, badusb

As stated in the title - is formatting my own USB stick on a separate computer with live-Ubuntu enough to prevent malware infection?

I work as computer technician and sometimes my pendrives must be plugged into potentially unsafe computers of my clients, which afterwards makes me think of how to properly clean them before using them again in my environment.

Can a BadUSB infect my pendrives' firmware through customer's PCs?

Comment: you can get thumbdrives with a physical read-only switch on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interesting `badusb` attacks all involve custom hardware. If you know that it is your USB drive just formatting it should be sufficient.